# Sending AMF header using idhttp

Tags: delphi, indy, amf

Is it possible to send AMF header to some site and get response

i have searched a lot but no luck

this is the code i use but i dont know how to write amf header (Post Data !)

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
 var
 SL: TStringList;
 HTTPAgent,FlexEngine ,FlexContent,ContentType:string;
begin


 HTTPAgent   := 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.86 Safari/537.36 OPR/33.0.1990.115';
 FlexEngine  := 'http://somesite.com/tools/amf.php';
 ContentType := 'application/x-amf';

 IdHTTP1.Request.UserAgent := HTTPAgent;

 SL := TStringList.Create;
 SL.Add(); // how to write the header

 IdHTTP1.Request.ContentType := ContentType;

 try
 memo1.Text :=  IdHTTP1.Post(FlexEngine, SL);
 finally
  SL.Free;
end;

end;
```

This how the post looks

[image: header Data from http analyzer]

Answer (score 2):

Posting data using a `TStringList` will format the data in the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format, which is not what you want to happen in this situation.  You need to post your AMF data using a `TStream` instead so it gets posted as-is, eg:

```
unit AMF;

interface

uses
  Classes;

procedure WriteUInt8ToStream(Stream: TStream; Value: Byte);
procedure WriteUInt16ToStream(Stream: TStream; Value: Word);
procedure WriteInt32ToStream(Stream: TStream; Value: Integer);
procedure WriteUInt32ToStream(Stream: TStream; Value: LongWord);
procedure WriteStringToStream(Stream: TStream; const Value: String);

implementation

uses
  IdStack;

procedure WriteUInt8ToStream(Stream: TStream; Value: Byte);
begin
  Stream.WriteBuffer(Value, Sizeof(Value));
end;

procedure WriteUInt16ToStream(Stream: TStream; Value: Word);
begin
  Value := GStack.HostToNetwork(UInt16(Value));
  Stream.WriteBuffer(Value, Sizeof(Value));
end;

procedure WriteInt32ToStream(Stream: TStream; Value: Integer);
begin
  Value := Integer(GStack.HostToNetwork(UInt32(Value)));
  Stream.WriteBuffer(Value, Sizeof(Value));
end;

procedure WriteUInt32ToStream(Stream: TStream; Value: LongWord);
begin
  Value := GStack.HostToNetwork(UInt32(Value));
  Stream.WriteBuffer(Value, Sizeof(Value));
end;

procedure WriteStringToStream(Stream: TStream; const Value: String);
var
  U: UTF8String;
  Len: Word;
begin
  U := UTF8String(Value); // or UTF8Encode(Value) if using D2007 or earlier
  Len := Min(Length(U), $FFFF);
  WriteUInt16ToStream(Stream, Len);
  Stream.WriteBuffer(PAnsiChar(U)^, Len * SizeOf(AnsiChar));
end;
```

```
uses
  AMF;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  MS: TMemoryStream;
  HTTPAgent, FlexEngine, FlexContent, ContentType: string;
begin
  HTTPAgent   := 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.86 Safari/537.36 OPR/33.0.1990.115';
  FlexEngine  := 'http://somesite.com/tools/amf.php';
  ContentType := 'application/x-amf';

  IdHTTP1.Request.UserAgent := HTTPAgent;

  MS := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    // write AMF data to stream as needed...
    AMF.WriteInt16ToStream(MS, 0); // version
    AMF.WriteUInt16ToStream(MS, 1); // header-count
    AMF.WriteStringToStream(MS, '...'); // header-name
    AMF.WriteUInt8ToStream(MS, 1); // must-understand
    AMF.WriteUInt32ToStream(MS, ...); // header-length
    // write header data as needed ...
    AMF.WriteUInt16ToStream(MS, 1); // message-count
    AMF.WriteStringToStream(MS, '...'); // target-uri
    AMF.WriteStringToStream(MS, '/1'); // response-uri
    AMF.WriteUInt32ToStream(MS, ...); // message-length
    // write message data as needed ...

    MS.Position := 0;

    IdHTTP1.Request.ContentType := ContentType;

    Memo1.Text := IdHTTP1.Post(FlexEngine, MS);
  finally
    MS.Free;
  end;
end;
```

I will leave it as an exercise for you to figure out how to write the AMF header and message data, based on the [AMF0](http://download.macromedia.com/pub/labs/amf/amf0_spec_121207.pdf) and [AMF3](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/amf/pdf/amf-file-format-spec.pdf) specifications.

Comment: Thank you Remy for the TIP , do you know how i could write the data ? it looks so complicated to me look at the picture :/ need to send svDirectAmf.getRoomData and array with string and boolean same as above :|

Comment: Have you ever worked with `TStream` before? It has `Write()` and `WriteBuffer()` methods.

Comment: i did what i can do but no success this is what i wrote http://imgur.com/RIkUX8T and this is the post data from the http analyzer http://imgur.com/oZ1eh49 why no body content ? ://  i was trying for hours but stuck in that body content  , what i did wrong ?

Comment: You changed the code I gave you. You separated `WriteUInt16ToStream()` from `WriteStringToStream()` (which was already calling `WriteUInt16ToStream()` for the string length), you removed the `AMF.` prefix from the function calls (now you have a conflict with Indy's `WriteStringToStream()`), and you set the `header_length` and `message_length` fields to 0 instead of actual sizes. Did you read the AMF specifications I linked you to? Everywhere I had `...` was meant for you to fill in, not ignore.